# providing Apex class when calling method from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am currently learning about LWC and Apex.

I'm trying to do a simple form app in which I would get data about a client that is to be searched in an API using Apex.

**LWC:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="First Name" required onchange={firstNameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Last Name" required onchange={lastNameChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Email" required onchange={emailChange}></lightning-input>
            <lightning-button variant="brand-outline" label="Search client" title="Brand action" onclick={handleOnclick} ></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ClientOperator extends LightningElement {
    firstName = '';
    lastName = '';
    email = '';

    firstNameChange(event){
        this.firstName = event.target.value;
    }

    lastNameChange(event){
        this.lastName = event.target.value;
    }

    emailChange(event){
        this.email = event.target.value;
    }

    handleOnclick(){
        console.log(this.firstName);
        console.log(this.lastName);
        console.log(this.email);
    }
}
```

I would like to trigger a call to the following Apex class :

```
public with sharing class ExerciseOrchestrator {
    public static void startFlow(Client client){
        String encodedClientKey = ClientService.searchClient(client);

        System.debug('Starting process.');

        if(encodedClientKey == null){
            System.debug('Client does not exist. Creating client.');
            encodedClientKey = ClientService.createClient(client);

            System.debug('Creating loan account for the client.');
            LoanAccountService.createAccount(encodedClientKey);

            System.debug('Creating deposits account for the client.');
            DepositAccountService.createAccount(encodedClientKey);
        }
        else{
            System.debug('Client exists.');

            if(DepositAccountService.searchAccount(encodedClientKey) == False){
                System.debug('Creating deposits account for the client.');
                DepositAccountService.createAccount(encodedClientKey);
            }
            else{
                System.debug('Client has deposits account.');
            }

            if(LoanAccountService.searchAccount(encodedClientKey) == False){
                System.debug('Creating loan account for the client.');
                LoanAccountService.createAccount(encodedClientKey);
            }
            else{
                System.debug('Client has loan account.');
            }
        }

        System.debug('Process finished. Exiting..');
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to provide the class member of the method (Client class) in the Javascript call. How would I do that? Also, if there's something wrong with my code please share.

Client class code:

```
public class Client {
    public String firstName {
      get { return firstName; }
      set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public String lastName {
      get { return lastName; }
      set { lastName = value; }
    }
    public String emailAddress {
      get { return emailAddress; }
      set { emailAddress = value; }
    }
    public String encodedKey {
      get { return encodedKey; }
      set { encodedKey = value; }
    }
    
    public Client(String firstName, String lastName, String emailAddress){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
    
    public override String toString(){
        return 'firstName: ' + this.firstName + '\n' 
            + 'lastName: ' + this.lastName + '\n' 
            + 'email: ' + this.emailAddress + '\n';
    }
}
```

later edit:

```
handleOnclick(){
        console.log(this.firstName);
        console.log(this.lastName);
        console.log(this.email);
        console.log('working??');

        const myClient = {
            firstName : this.firstName,
            lastName : this.lastName,
            emailAddress : this.email
        }

        console.log(myClient);

        console.log('working??');

        startFlow({ client: myClient })
            .then((result) => {
                this.error = undefined;
                console.log('done');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

As indicated, I implemented it this way.
However, it seems like the call is not made and I have no idea how to debug it, how would I see the logs of the execution for example?

Comment: You should probably follow the Trailhead modules on LWC in order understand this.

Comment: Is Client a "concrete" class, or is it "virtual" or "abstract"?

Comment: the problem is not calling the method itself. it is providing the "client" parameter for the startFlow method. I will add the client implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative) for this. You need to import the apex method and then call it within your code and handle the results. In your case something like this.

```
import startFlow from '@salesforce/apex/ExerciseOrchestrator.startFlow';

...

handleOnclick(){
    console.log(this.firstName);
    console.log(this.lastName);
    console.log(this.email);
    const client = {
        //fill in client object
    };
    startFlow({ client: client })
        .then()
        .catch();
}
```

And your method needs to be annotated as `AuraEnabled`.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
```

Comment: the problem is not calling the method itself. it is providing the "client" parameter for the startFlow method.

Comment: so from what I understand I would actually have to call the method with a plain object that resembles the class in the Apex code.

Comment: yes, and the class probably will need to be annotated as public, AuraEnable, with getters and setters. But this depends on location of the class, if it is inner or in separate file

Comment: any ideas on how could I see the logs of the method execution? I have modified the code with all recommendations but it seems like nothing is being executed.

Comment: front end will be logged in the console log of your browser and the server side (apex) will be logged in apex logs

Comment: yes. but I am not aware how to access apex logs if the execution of a method is triggered in javascript.

Comment: it will run under your user, so just set logging on your user.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it right. To pass in parameters, you use a parameter object:

```
startFlow({client: myClient})
```

Using the syntax from your later code:

```
startFlow(client = myClient)
```

Would assign the value in `myClient` to a variable named `client` in your JS code (in other words, nothing would get passed to the server correctly).

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative) for more information.

Comment: indeed realised the mistake I have made.
Now it seems like nothing is being executed, and I have no clue of how to debug or even see the logs resulted from the method execution.

Comment: @ionut.baltariu in your browser, check F12 (Developer Console) to see if the Console tab has any errors, and the Network tab to see if the API call was made. Assuming everything is good there, use Salesforce Developer Console (in the ⚙ menu) to check the logs there.

Comment: no logs appear in the Developer console. Should the methods from the classes that are called in the ExerciseOrchestrator also be market as AuraEnabled, or should they be @future marked, does that hold any relevance?

Comment: @ionut.baltariu They should be `@AuraEnabled`, and they must *not* be `@future`.

Comment: I reassured they're all annotated but it seems like nothing is being executed on the back-end side. Logs do not appear in the developer console and neither in the setup menu on my salesforce playground.

Comment: @ionut.baltariu make sure all the code is in the correct org, I guess. I'm not sure what else to say. You've got something fundamentally wrong with your setup.

Comment: I managed to get my hands on some logs and this is the triggered exception:
16:39:25.3 (9848741)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[EXTERNAL]|System.TypeException: Client does not have a no-arg constructor @sfdcfox